# MySQL select MAX date from joined table

Tags: mysql, date, select, join, max

I have this `MySQL` query:

```
SELECT 
    s.student_id,
    s.student_firstname,
    s.student_lastname,
    sd.student_startdate,
    sd.student_enddate,
    s.isActive,
    c.city_name,
    ctc.category_name
FROM
    students s
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT sd1.student_id, sd1.student_startdate, sd1.student_enddate FROM studentdates sd1) sd ON sd.student_id = s.student_id
        INNER JOIN
    cityselections c ON c.city_id = s.student_city_id
        INNER JOIN
    coursecategory ctc ON s.student_course_category_id = ctc.category_id
WHERE
    sd.student_enddate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
        AND s.student_city_id NOT LIKE '1'
        AND s.student_city_id = 18
        AND s.isActive = 1
GROUP BY s.student_id
ORDER BY sd.student_enddate ASC , s.student_lastname , s.student_firstname
```

In the table `studentdates` there can be multiple `student_startdate` and `student_enddate` on each `student_id` but I want to select each students `MAX(student_enddate)`.

How can this be done?

Comment: just use this function `MAX(student_enddate);`

Comment: Yeah tried it everywhere but still does not select the highest date for some reason.

Comment: WHERE sd.student_enddate= (
    SELECT MAX(sd.student_enddate)
    FROM tablename and if you want to put any where condition
)

Comment: MAX(student_enddate) may not work if student_enddate stores values like 2013-08-28. I think the date is cast to an integer, which would just use 2013 when calculating the max.

Perhaps using MIN(), MAX(), and DATEDIFF() would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify your subquery as follows:

```
(
    SELECT
        sd1.student_id, sd1.student_startdate, sd1.student_enddate
    FROM (
        SELECT student_id, MAX(student_enddate) AS enddate
        FROM studentdates
        GROUP BY student_id
    ) AS s_max_enddate
    JOIN studentdates AS sd1 ON (
        sd1.student_id = s_max_enddate.student_id
        AND sd1.student_enddate = s_max_enddate.enddate
    )
)
```

Comment: Just brilliant. This solved my problem and was a perfect answer to my question!